# Show the tooltip in SimpleTip plugin on load

Tags: jquery, show, onload, simpletip

I am using the SimpleTip plugin for showing a pop up message in my site. I would like to show the text immediately when the page loads, and not on the hover or on Click event. Is there a way to do something like this? I tried use the show(), that is suppose to work, but could not make it work.

```
$("#myDiv").simpletip({ 
    fixed: true, 
    position: 'bottom'
}).show();
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure for insert these tags in head:

```
<link href="code.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="simpletip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

its worked.

Comment: I have them, the simpleTip works fine. The show() on this simpleTip is not working.

Comment: the show event make your tag to unhide object. if you have this: `<div style="display:none;background:black;width:100px;height:100px;" id="myDiv"></div>` ; when you use the .show() you bring this div to 'display:block'.